# EM_ASM is not yet supported in shared wasm module

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

When I compile c files with emscripten，
I used public API called emscripten.h

```
#include <iostream>

    int main() {
      std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    }
```

The terminal feedback error is as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/emcc", line 13, in <module>
    emcc.run()
  File "/emscripten/emcc.py", line 1524, in run
    final = shared.Building.emscripten(final, append_ext=False, extra_args=extra_args)
  File "/emscripten/tools/shared.py", line 2011, in emscripten
    call_emscripten(cmdline)
  File "/emscripten/emscripten.py", line 2195, in _main
    temp_files.run_and_clean(lambda: main(
  File "/emscripten/tools/tempfiles.py", line 78, in run_and_clean
    return func()
  File "/emscripten/emscripten.py", line 2200, in <lambda>
    DEBUG=DEBUG,
  File "/emscripten/emscripten.py", line 2100, in main
    temp_files=temp_files, DEBUG=DEBUG)
  File "/emscripten/emscripten.py", line 102, in emscript
    function_tables_and_exports(funcs, metadata, mem_init, glue, forwarded_data, settings, outfile, DEBUG))
  File "/emscripten/emscripten.py", line 251, in function_tables_and_exports
    pre = include_asm_consts(pre, forwarded_json, metadata, settings)
  File "/emscripten/emscripten.py", line 643, in include_asm_consts
    assert len(metadata['asmConsts']) == 0, 'EM_ASM is not yet supported in shared wasm module (it cannot be stored in the wasm itself, need some solution)'
AssertionError: EM_ASM is not yet supported in shared wasm module (it cannot be stored in the wasm itself, need some solution)
```

how to fixed it?

Comment: add your code/error in the post please.

Comment: Don't try to show images of text. Copy-paste it *as text* instead. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you. I was the first to ask, sorry.